# Symfony 2 form including invalid data in custom message

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
$builder->add('some_field', 'some_type', array(
    // ...
    'invalid_message'            => 'You entered an invalid value: %1%',
    'invalid_message_parameters' => array('%1%' => ?),
));
```

My problem is, I can't figure out where to get the value for %1%.

From reading the docs and doing searching this is what I came up with. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation again, you will see that specific example you are copying here is only available for some formTypes (as integer) is not for doing what you want to achieve.

Read [this first](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html). There you have a lot of Constraint examples and how to set up the right error messages.

From your code, you cannot guess what you want to do, because there is not any Contraint that defining that the input value is invalid.
I suggest doing the validation in the entities, if you can do so, so you can keep them in Resources/config/validation.yml

Then you can do something like:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
properties:
    email:
        - Email:
            message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
```

Where value will print what you want. Like that you can define a [custom Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) if you need so.

Answer (score 0):

If your form is based on an Entity you should use a validation.yml file to use constraints. If not (or if you are lazy) you can also add your constraints in your form with php like this:

```
#Load the constraint you are going to use (for example length, which put min or max limits to your input length
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
# ...
#then in your controller or formtype where you build your form:
$form=$this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('newPassword', 'password', array(
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new Length(array(
                    'min' => 8,
                    'minMessage' => 'You have entered {{ value }} which is under the limit length {{ limit }}')))))
        ->getForm();
```

In this example I build a password input which have to be above the limit (8). Note how I implement the `length` constraint in this input. Then you print the message using `{{ value }}` to access the entered value. You should find how different constraints implement messages, in the case of the 'length constraint' you can set a 'minMessage' and a 'maxMessage' for others constraints you can use only a 'message'.

Answer (score 0):

If you like me were searching for the validation message to be set on throwing `TransformationFailedException`, you could simply use `{{ value }}` which is pre-populated by Symfony.

```
$builder->add('some_field', 'some_type', array(
    // ...
    'invalid_message' => 'You entered an invalid value: {{ value }}'
));
```